# Aws EC2 and Route 53 connection

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm trying to connect domain (bought with Amazon r53) and EC2 instance. So far I have

- got elastic IP and attached to the instance
- added that elastic IP to r53 traffic record (A, TTL 300, simple routing)

  ping resolves assigned elastic IP correctly but sent packets are 100% lost.

Am I missing a step here? Something obvious?

Comment: Do you have an inbound security group rule on the EC2 host allowing ICMP from your IP address?

Comment: I have set both inbound and outbound rules to all traffic, just to make sure it was not the issue.
* i can however connect via SSH / FTP, just not http.

Comment: And what service is listening on port 80 (http)? Did you configure a web server on this EC2 instance?

Comment: @Appleoddity you know what? i am f'ing stupid. Forgot to turn on web server on instance. 
Facepalming so hard =(